# HTML: How to make html Japanese encoding display properly on Mac?

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding, cjk

I have been making a webpage using some Japanese font. The encoding **is correct on Windows** (Chrome), but however when I open it ***on OSX (safari / chrome), the encoding becomes weird*** with greek and all other characters. How can I fix it?

Here is a part of my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    // Other Stuff
</head>
<body>
 var list = ["ｱ", "ｲ", "ｳ", "ｴ", "ｵ", "ｶ", "ｷ", "ｸ", "ｹ", "ｺ", "ｻ", "ｼ", "ｽ", "ｾ", "ｿ", "ﾀ", "ﾁ", "ﾂ", "ﾃ", "ﾄ", "ﾅ", "ﾆ", "ﾇ", "ﾈ", "ﾉ", "ﾊ", "ﾋ", "ﾌ", "ﾍ", "ﾎ", "ﾏ", "ﾐ", "ﾑ", "ﾒ", "ﾓ", "ﾔ", "ﾕ", "ﾖ", "ﾗ", "ﾘ", "ﾙ", "ﾚ", "ﾛ", "ﾜ", "ｦ", "ﾝ"];
 // Block of code that uses these characters
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should also use appropriate  font family

Comment: also the first line should be <!DOCTYPE html>.  You have  duplicate declaration of jquery

Comment: @srp The first jQuery line was inserted from the Stack Snippet. Of course, it shouldn’t be used, if jQuery is already included.

Comment: If you haven’t set everything to UTF-8, do so.

Comment: yea the first jquery was inserted by stacksnippet ignore that

Comment: and I declared a font-family in css and it fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: but havent i not declared everything in UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

Please additionally set the appropriate font family to resolve the issue.

It is not enough that you set the correct encoding. i.e UTF-8, 
You should also set appropriate font/font-family that can show you the correct symbol based on the encoding.

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what font-family I should use?